# What are the arguments for scipy.stats.uniform?

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to create a uniform distribution between two numbers (lower bound and upper bound) in order to feed it to sklearn's [ParameterSampler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.ParameterSampler.html). I am using [scipy.stats.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) in the following format:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform    
params = ParameterSampler({'bandwidth':uniform(5,50)}, 20)
```

But when I get the random selections of the 'bandwidth' parameter, they are not all between 5 and 50. Some of them are bigger than 50 by a bit. So my question is what do the arguments in scipy.stats.uniform represent? Are they not a lower bound and upper bound? The documentation shows no arguments so I can't figure it out from that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The first argument is the lower bound, and the second argument is the range of the distribution. So the example distribution in your question is uniform between 5 and 55.

Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.uniform.html) linked in your question:

> A uniform continuous random variable.
>
> This distribution is constant between `loc` and `loc + scale`.

`loc` is the first argument and `scale` is the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough and prompt response. Very helpful. How did you know that loc and scale were the two arguments?

Comment: Basically, experience with using `uniform` and various other scipy probability distributions before, which all take `loc` and `scale` parameters. That documentation would have been pretty unclear to me without some prior experience.

Answer (score 4):

In the given case the call should look like that:

```
uniform.rvs(loc=5, scale=45)
```

Even though it's possible to call the distribution directly with parameters, `scipy.stats` has the following logic:

```
<dist_name>.rvs(loc=<param1>, scale=<param2>, size=(Nx, Ny))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `loc` is the lower bound and `scale` is upper bound subtracted from the lower bound.

#### Function

Here is a function to do that for you:

```
from scipy.stats import uniform

def get_uniform(min, max):
    """Transform min (lower bound) and max (upper bound) 
    to scipy.stats.uniform parameters"""
    return uniform(loc=min, scale=max-min)
```

### Proof

I tested it with this:

```
size = 100000

experiments = [
    (5_000, 10_000),
    (-10_000, -5_000),
    (-1_000, 0),
    (0, 1_000),
]

for lb, ub in experiments:
    print(f"Experiment (Lower: {lb}, Upper: {ub})")

    rand_values = get_uniform(min=lb, max=ub).rvs(size)
    print(f"Observed range: {int(round(rand_values.min(), 0))} to {int(round(rand_values.max(), 0))}")
    print()
```

Which gives:

```
Experiment (Lower: 5000, Upper: 10000)
Observed range: 5000 to 10000

Experiment (Lower: -10000, Upper: -5000)
Observed range: -10000 to -5000

Experiment (Lower: -1000, Upper: 0)
Observed range: -1000 to 0

Experiment (Lower: 0, Upper: 1000)
Observed range: 0 to 1000
```

Which is exactly as you would expect.